# Is this a hijack?

Tags: windows-7, browser, malware, hijack

My home router was down the other day.  I tried to use chrome, and I got the following error message:

`DNS Lookup for "www.searchpage.com" failed. The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found`

What in the world is SearchPage.com, and why is my chrome going there?

I have Windows 7 with Microsoft Security Essentials for protection.

Comment: It sounds like you have some sort of browser hijacker on your machine, or some other malware, which is redirecting you through the searchpage.com website

Comment: Yea, looks like that: http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/280490-dns-lookup-fails-but-only-web-browsers.html

Comment: Take a look at [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360/97028) for help to clean your PC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Its a "popular" malware who usually comes with freeware programs:

1. Uninstall it from Computer through Control Panel
2. Check for unwanted installed plugins
3. Restore the original search engines of your browser.

Plus, add a new line in your hosts file:

%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Add this line at the end:

127.0.0.1 www.searchpage.com

Answer (score -1):

Looks like malware. I recommend you use a malware scanner to get rid of it. If problems persist, try factory resetting your router or contact your ISP.